# python Recursive folders

Tags: python, recursion

I need to download all txt files from a site, how do I check all folders for files and download them.

The path format I need to have is "https://downloadsite.com/folder1/file.txt". How do I go about having the a function loop on all folders and list all file path like as shown below:

```
https://downloadsite.com/folder2/folder2a/file2a.txt
https://downloadsite.com/folder2/folder2a/folder2aa/file2aa.txt

folder1 ---> file1.txt
folder2 ---> folder2a ---->file2a.txt
   |-------> file2.txt   
   |
   |-------> folder2aa ---> file2aa.txt
```

Comment: Are you running the Python program on the download site, or on a remote site? The techniques will vary accordingly. And, if on a remote site, how do you expect to navigate that site? Via http/https?

Comment: Sounds like you need a [web spider / crawler](http://scrapy.org/). [This might do](https://github.com/aitjcize/creepy). Or you could just [write something with urllib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html).

Comment: @JonathanEunice I download from a remote site. I use wget to the download the files.import os
os.system("command")

Comment: @AnthonyPanaglima If you're just using wget, why not use [recursive wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Recursive-Retrieval-Options)? Or, depending on your use case, you might just want to use a tool like [DirBuster](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_DirBuster_Project).

Comment: @AnthonyPanaglima Then your problem isn't exclusively with Python. You need a web crawler, as @ParthianShot says. But even then... Unless you know the list of files beforehand, or have some way to get a list, it won't work. Some web sites will show you directory contents; others will not. HTML files have links you can follow--but `.txt` files do not. You are trying to do something much, much harder than you know.

Comment: Jus tto add to what @JonathanEunice mentioned, it's kind of impossible to do what you want to do if the owner of the website doesn't link to documents under the given directory, and their names are more than a few characters long. However, if you want to make sure you get everything that's linked to, you can leverage the power of [Google dorks](https://www.google.com/#q=site:jwz.org%2Fblog), and the [Google custom search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview).